# "node module " missing error in jenkins pipeline build

Tags: docker, npm, dockerfile, npm-install, devops

I have dockerfile containing the angular build section as below.

```
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
    RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
    RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN npm config set registry https://shnexus0.sohard.de/repository/sedi.npm.development/
RUN npm i -g @angular/cli@latest
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g typescript
```

In the jenkins pipeline build I am getting the below error.

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! dicom-web-viewer@0.0.0 tsc: `tsc`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the dicom-web-viewer@0.0.0 tsc script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
```

Even though I have npm install in the dockerfile. It is showing the error for node module. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever able to solve this?